# How do I post to an application's wall using Fb C# Sdk?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I've been trying to post something to my application's timeline/feed/wall on Fb, for the better part of the day but I keep failing. This is getting frustrating.

What I'm doing is : I'm having a simple console C# app, that is trying to post something on the application's wall (a basic hello world!, for instance).

This snippet shows how I'm retrieving an access token :

```
 private string _AccessToken;
        public string AccessToken
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_AccessToken))
                {
                    //_AccessToken = string.Format("{0}|{1}", Credentials.AppId, Credentials.AppSecret);
                    Logger.Debug("Attempting to retrieve the access token...");
                    dynamic result = ExecuteGet("oauth/access_token", new
                    {
                        client_id = Credentials.AppId, // my app id
                        client_secret = Credentials.AppSecret, // my app secret
                        grant_type = "client_credentials",
                        scope = "manage_pages,publish_actions,publish_stream"
                    }, false);

                    _AccessToken = result.access_token;
                }
                Logger.Debug("Operation succeeded, access token is : {0}", _AccessToken);
                return _AccessToken;
            }
        }

private object ExecuteGet(string path, object parameters)
        {
            return ExecuteGet(path, parameters, true);
        }

        private object ExecuteGet(string path, object parameters, bool useAccessToken)
        {
            try
            {
                Logger.Debug("Executing GET : {0}", path);
                var client = useAccessToken ? new FacebookClient(AccessToken) : new FacebookClient();
                return client.Get(path, parameters);
            }
            catch (FacebookApiException ex)
            {
                Logger.Error("GET Operation failed : {0}", ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

And this is how I'm trying to actually post something :

```
public void PostToApplicationWall(string message)
        {
            string path = string.Format("/{0}/feed", Credentials.AppId);
            IDictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "description", "[DESCRIPTION] Facebook description..." },
                { "link", "http://tinyurl.org" },
                { "name", "[NAME] Facebook name..." },
                { "caption", "[CAPTION] Facebook caption..." },
                { "message", message }
            };

            dynamic result = ExecutePost(path, parameters);
        }

private object ExecutePost(string path, object parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                Logger.Debug("Executing POST : {0}", path);
                var client = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
                return client.Post(path, parameters);
            }
            catch (FacebookApiException ex)
            {
                Logger.Error("POST Operation failed : {0}", ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Please note that ExecutePost() uses the AccessToken property, I've pasted in the beginning.

The message that I'm getting is : **(OAuthException - #210) (#210) Subject must be a page**

Please help, I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

App profile pages are discontinued since Feburary 1st 2012. You have to create an app page. Read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/).

Now, when you have an app page, you change your code like this:

```
string path = string.Format("/{0}/feed", Credentials.PageId);
```

OR

```
string path = string.Format("/{0}/feed", Credentials.PageUsername);
```

[EDIT]
For posting to a page, you need the page access token instead of app access token. Read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/) on how to get a page access token.

Comment: Thanks, I'll explore this asap.

Comment: Ok, I've followed the route you've described - and now I'm getting exception 200 : (OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action -> still a bit confusing b/c I'm not doing this as a user, but rather as an app? Can you offer any further advice? The scope in the token includes "publish_stream" so I should be good to post something to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Maciek, if you really just want to post to your own page, writing a standalone app may not be the easiest way to do this. Have you tried PowerShell and http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com? This module will take care of the permissioning for you, and let you do this operation with a simple script.

Comment: Interesting, I'll definitely look into it, although I don't intend to use PowerShell :)